# CollectionView 2 sections. How to access the outlet vars from inner class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview

I have 2 sections in my collection view: Images and Albums.
Each section has its own logic. By clicking on album - some photos are uploaded.
By clicking on Image I want to access outlet UIView variable, but I can't since didSelectItemAt indexPath method inside inner class.

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet var pickedPhotoView: UIView!

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AlbumCell


           <b>// Here is ok. i can access the pickedPhotoView variable</b>

            view.addSubview(pickedPhotoView)


        }


    class ImagesCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // but here there is no chance to access pickedPhotoView variable


    }
}
```

**update:**

```
 class TwoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, ImagesCellDelegate {

        func doSomething(_ sender: ImagesCell) {
            print("do something")
        }


        var imagesCell: ImagesCell = ImagesCell()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            imagesCell.delegate = self
       }
}

protocol ImagesCellDelegate {
    func doSomething(_ sender: ImagesCell)
}

class ImagesCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var delegate: ImagesCellDelegate!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        delegate?.doSomething(self)

    }
}
```

doSomething func not executed in TwoViewController.
I guess I am doing something wrong with:

```
var imagesCell: ImagesCell = ImagesCell()
imagesCell.delegate = self
```

Any ideas?
Thanx!

The solution is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     cell.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Why is the cell posing as the collection view delegate? Make the controller be the delegate...

Comment: Mohit Athwani, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make a comment because i do not have enough reputation, but your question is not clear.
You have 2 section --> you can determine the current selecting section in TwoViewController.

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
// album
} else if indexPath.section == 1 {
// photo 
}
```

Or if you want to trigger when user interact into each particular cell, you might use delegate or closure/block callback.

Answer (score 0):

Why you must make ImagesCell as inner class?
" Instance member 'pickedPhotoView' of type 'TwoViewController' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'TwoViewController.ImagesCell' "
You can make ImagesCell outside of TwoViewController just as AlbumCell.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, you need delegate pattern in iOS.

- https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

---

#### Codes as following.

```
class ImagesCell : : UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var delegate: ImagesCellDelegate!
}

protocol ImagesCellDelegate {
    func doSomething()
}

extension TwoViewController: ImagesCellDelegate {
    func doSomething() {
        // pickedPhotoView can be accessed here
    }
}
```

---

#### More

`UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` should not access member variables in `UIViewController`. Those cell should focus on their UI presentation, and should not involve any knowledge about it's parent view controller.

In this manner, those cells can be reused in another UIViewController easily. Those UIViewController just knows when they want to use `ImagesCell`, they `MUST` implement `ImageCellDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I tried it, but function doSomething() does not caught in my main controller - TwoViewContrller

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, ImagesCellDelegate {

        func doSomething(_ sender: ImagesCell) {
            print("do something")
        }


        var imagesCell: ImagesCell = ImagesCell()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            imagesCell.delegate = self
       }
}

protocol ImagesCellDelegate {
    func doSomething(_ sender: ImagesCell)
}

class ImagesCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var delegate: ImagesCellDelegate!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        delegate?.doSomething(self)

    }
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         // just added this code in function
         cell.delegate = self
    }
```